# Por que a tag <picture> do HTML5 não está redimensionando as imagens?

Tags: html, html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 490px)" srcset="img/smartphone.jpg"/>
   <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img/bola.jpg"/>
   <img src="img/geometria.jpg"/>
</picture>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O código que colocou nem tem essa tag

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**OBS:** Primeiramente acredito que vc tenha se confundido no título da pergunta, pois falou de `<figure>`, mas no código vc colocou `<picture>`, de qq forma, seu problema é com a ordem das tags...</sup>

Seu problema é simples, quando se usa `min-width` o maior valor sempre tem que vir primeiro

Primeiro `650px` e depois `490px`, se nao for nessa ordem o valor de `490px` vai sobrescrever tudo que vier após

```
<source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://placecage.com/300/100" />
<source media="(min-width: 490px)" srcset="http://placecage.com/200/100" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://placecage.com/300/100" />
    <source media="(min-width: 490px)" srcset="http://placecage.com/200/100" />
    <img src="http://placecage.com/100/100" />
</picture>
```